# Why are the two daylight prayers done silently, and the others out loud?

Tags: salat

In the time of nabi Muhammad, zuhr (noon) and asr (afternoon) prayers were being done silent, because in the daytime there were some enemies who jeered when they heard the prayers.

However, today, we don't have such problems. Why are we still doing daytime prayers silent?

Rather than reading quoted fatwa from other site, I want to learn if they continue to pray silently even after the the jeering of mushriks had ended in the following years. If they continued, didn't any sahaba offered the nabi to pray the prayers out loud as they did in the past? Someone must have brought that subject to debate for sure. What was the nabi's answer?

Answer (score 3):

If a ruling is established in sharee’ah for a reason that no longer applies, and this ruling is in accordance with the fitrah or is one of the symbols of Islam, then it remains even if the reason no longer applies. Raml (walking at a fast pace) in tawaaf was originally intended so that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and his companions could demonstrate physical strength in front of the mushrikeen who said:

> There have come to you people who have been weakened by the fever of
>   Yathrib.

This reason no longer applies, but the ruling remains in effect, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) did raml in the Farewell Pilgrimage. So, we do it to follow the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) who we consider as the best guide.

Apart from that, if you are not going to follow what Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) [whose guidance is the best] did, then people are going to come up with new alternatives to corrupt the religion. Would you consider that as a better thing to follow?

However, in any case, loud or silent, your prayer is valid but it is better if you follow the example of the Prophet.

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:

> Reciting out loud in the prayers where this is done is not obligatory,
>   rather it is what is better. If a person recites silently in a prayer
>   in which it is prescribed to recite out loud, his prayer is not
>   invalid, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) said: “There is no prayer for one who does not recite the Essence
>   of the Book (al-Faatihah).” He did not specify whether this recitation
>   is to be out loud or silent. So if a person recites what he is
>   required to recite, silently or out loud, then he has fulfilled his
>   duty. But it is better to recite out loud in the prayers where doing
>   so is customary, as in Fajr and Jumu’ah prayers.
>
> If a person deliberately does not recite out loud when he is leading
>   the prayer, his prayer is valid but it is lacking.
>
> If a person is praying alone, he has the choice between reciting out
>   loud or silently. He should look at what is more likely to increase
>   his focus and humility in prayer, and do that.

Majmoo’ Fataawa Ibn ‘Uthaymeen, 13/73

Source: [What is the reason why Qur’aan is recited out loud in some prayers and silently in others?](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/67672/)

Comment: `Imitating the prophet` is different from `following his path`. Prophet also ordered us to throw arrows to enemies at war. Must we still use arrows today? Is sunnah just imitating as is? The life of nabi is an example for us, not a mold to give the exact shape and appearance.

Comment: @AhmedHan There are two things with respect to Islam: Ritualistic and Non-ritualistic. The Salaat is ritualistic and in the ritualistic part of Islam, we try to imitate and follow the example of Prophet. The non-ritualistic part has no boundaries unless it involves haraam actions. For e.g. Prophet(saw) sent letters that doesn't mean we shouldn't use emails. Your example comes under non-ritualistic. Another thing is it is known as a custom with Prophet that he used to wear a type of slipper customary to Arabs, but it is not something legislated as Sunnah.

Comment: I prefer to say "including symbolic body movements" rather than calling it "ritualistic". If salat had a fixed form, then why did the nabi made modification on it because of some mushriks making fun of them? There are some principles in Islam which the nabi did never give up defending even if he was tortured. But there are some other details, he made changes on them according to conditions he faced. And this example is one of that changes, we even know the reason of this change.

Comment: @AhmedHan You say you know the reason. I say Allah knows the best. What you say as "some enemies who jeered when they heard the prayers" might be one of the reason. There are other reasons like that at night and at the time of Fajr prayer, people are more likely to benefit from recitation that is done out loud, as there are less distractions around them than at the time of Zuhr and ‘Asr. If we were to rationalize every ritual in Islam, I think that is a bad idea. Allah says -" whatever the Messenger has given you - take; and what he has forbidden you - refrain from."[59:7]

Comment: @AhmedHan He doesn't say rationalize and then follow.

Answer (score 1):

Allah has specified how should your voice be when doing your prayers. Anything other than it is a personal preference and is not mandatory:

> قُلِ ادْعُوا اللَّهَ أَوِ ادْعُوا الرَّحْمَٰنَ أَيًّا مَّا تَدْعُوا
>   فَلَهُ الْأَسْمَاءُ الْحُسْنَىٰ وَلَا تَجْهَرْ بِصَلَاتِكَ وَلَا
>   تُخَافِتْ بِهَا وَابْتَغِ بَيْنَ ذَٰلِكَ سَبِيلًا ﴿الإسراء: ١١٠﴾
>
> Say: 'Call upon Allah, or call upon the Merciful; whichsoever you call
>   upon, to Him belong the Names Most Beautiful.' And be thou not loud in
>   thy prayer, nor hushed therein, but seek thou for a way between that.

Answer (score -3):

If you think about it during Ramadan these 2 prayers are at a time when your throat is dry and will be difficult to recite the Quran. It's best to do it in silent.